# How to inject dependency into InvalidModelStateResponseFactory delegate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a Scoped service that handles all errors in my application, along with supplementary info I want to return as part of my error response. As errors are raised I add them to this service and as it is scoped it keeps track of all errors for a particular request and allows me to ignore or return them at various points in my code.

```
public interface IErrorHandlingService 
{
    MyErrorResponse ErrorResponse { get; }
    void AddRequestInformation(Guid trace, DateTime timestamp, string requestRoute);
    void AddError(MyCustomError error);
    bool HasErrors();
}
```

I want to handle any model binding errors via this service to keep the format of my error responses consistent. I've made the (possibly silly) assumption that `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` is a delegate that would be called at the point of a single request failing the model binding validation, so how would I pass my scoped error handler to this in order to use it in the function? Is this possible?

My instinct is to assign it inside the `services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(...)` call but I can't work out the "right" way to access my service inside there.

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = (actionContext) =>
    {
        var errHandler = // ???

        var errors = actionContext.ModelState
            .Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
            .Select(e => e.Value);

        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            errHandler.AddError(new MyCustomError()
            {
                // whatever
            });
        }

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(errors);
    };
});
```

Comment: Good question, next is how to await an async method from your dependency/injectable :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find the answer before I'd even finished writing the question - I can access the services via `actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices` so the line in my example above where I assign the `errHandler` would be:

```
var errHandler = (IErrorHandlingService)actionContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IErrorHandlingService));
```